# json creation with one key and multiple values

Tags: python

I want a json like this in python list

column = ['orderID', 'productID', 'unitPrice', 'quantity', 'discount']

I converted to dictionary and i am getting like this

{'orderID': 'field', 'productID': 'field', 'unitPrice': 'field', 'quantity': 'field', 'discount': 'field'}

But I need output as below:

"ColumnNames":[
{
"field":"Status"
},
{
"field":"order"
},
{
"field":"discount"
},
{
"field":"product"
},
{
"field":"quantity"
},
{
"field":"price"
}
],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 column = ['orderID', 'productID', 'unitPrice', 'quantity', 'discount']
 list_of_dictionary = [{"field": i} for i in column]
 result={"ColumnNames":list_of_dictionary}
 print(result)
```